# I am currently cooking a grenade in stealth. How do I put it away?

Tags: payday-3

I may have hit the wrong button while trying to answer a radio

[image: stealth phase of a heist with a flashbang in hand]

How do I put this grenade away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Do not panic. **Continue holding your grenade key so you don't throw it.**

Step 2: **While holding down your grenade key**, press any of your weapon switch keys.

Congratulations, you have put the flashbang back into your pocket.